# Move a UIView object when ViewController is rotated

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a custom UIView that I'm using for the UITableView header.  I'm creating it in code.  (I'm basically following the TVAnimationGestures from WWDC 2010).  For UI elements that are some offset from the left hand side, it looks good in either orientation.  However, if I want a UILabel that is offset from the right hand size, I'm not sure what to do.  If I were in IB, I would use the springs/struts.  But not sure how to do that in code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

springs/struts in IB is a GUI interface to autoresizingMask:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6

For right justification, You want to position the label with the correct offset when you first create it and set autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin (and any other that you want.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to implement a method in the view which will place it's subviews according to the UIInterfaceOrientation.

You can then call this method from the UIViewController when the rotation is detected.

For example:

In YourView.h

```
@interface YourView : UIView {

}

// Public API
- (void)placeWidgetsForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

@end
```

In YourView.m

```
#import "YourView.h"

@implementation YourView

...

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public API

- (void)placeWidgetsForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Change frames of subviews according to orientation in here
}

@end
```

Then in YourController.m

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    YourView *theView = (YourView *) self.view; // Or where ever your view is
    [theView placeWidgetsForInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```